# For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, find the values for$\big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^i i! \big) \mod 36$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, induction, divisibility

I did some calculations and found out that for $n=1,2,3,4$ the remainders are $35,1,31,19$ respectively. From then on I conjectured that the remainder was always 7. I then attempted  to prove this by simple induction on $n$. For $n=5$ it checked out.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (-1)^i i!  = \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^i i! \bigg) + (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!$$

But this amounts to proving that $36\mid (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!$ for all $n\geq 5$. We can do simple induction on $n$ a second time. This new hypothesis is true for 5. And

$$(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)! = (-1)(-1)^{n+1}(n+2)(n+1)! = k(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!$$

Which follows from the induction hypothesis and the properties of divisibility. Hence the remainder is 7 for all $n\geq 5$.

Is this reasoning more or less correct?

Comment: Yes, or note that any $(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!$ for $n\ge 5$ contains a factor of $2\cdot 3\cdot 6$.

Comment: Yes. For $n\ge 6$ the expression is $A+B$ where $A=\sum_{i=1}^5i!(-1)^i $ and 
 $B=\sum_{i=6}^ni!(-1)^i,$  and every term in the formula for $B$ is divisible by $6!,$ and $36|6!, $ so $B\equiv 0 \mod 36$.